# Entity Framework telling me an object is attached when it isn't - why?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, objectcontext

I have an object I want to update in the database. I'm new to EF but have done a fair bit of reading. Clearly my approach is wrong, but I don't understand why. FYI the Context referenced throughout is an ObjectContext which is newly instantiated as this code begins and is disposed immediately after. Here is my Update method - the View is the object I want to update in the database and it has 4 ICollection properties whose changes I also wish to save to the database:

```
    public void Update(View view)
    {
        var original = Read(view.Username, view.ViewId);

        original.ViewName = view.ViewName;

        ProcessChanges<CostCentre, short>(Context.CostCentres, original.CostCentres, view.CostCentres, "iFinanceEntities.CostCentres", "CostCentreId");

        ProcessChanges<LedgerGroup, byte>(Context.LedgerGroups, original.LedgerGroups, view.LedgerGroups, "iFinanceEntities.LedgerGroups", "LedgerGroupId");

        ProcessChanges<Division, byte>(Context.Divisions, original.Divisions, view.Divisions, "iFinanceEntities.Divisions", "DivisionId");

        ProcessChanges<AnalysisCode, short>(Context.AnalysisCodes, original.AnalysisCodes, view.AnalysisCodes, "iFinanceEntities.AnalysisCodes", "AnalysisCodeId");

        int test = Context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

First I get the original from the database because I want to compare its collections with the new set of collections. This should ensure the correct sub-objects are added and removed. I compare each collection in turn using this ProcessChanges method:

```
    private void ProcessChanges<TEntity, TKey>(ObjectSet<TEntity> contextObjects, ICollection<TEntity> originalCollection, ICollection<TEntity> changedCollection, string entitySetName, string pkColumnName) 
        where TEntity : class, ILookupEntity<TKey>
    {
        List<TKey> toAdd = changedCollection
            .Select(c => c.LookupKey)
            .Except(originalCollection.Select(o => o.LookupKey))
            .ToList();

        List<TKey> toRemove = originalCollection
            .Select(o => o.LookupKey)
            .Except(changedCollection.Select(c => c.LookupKey))
            .ToList();

        toAdd.ForEach(a =>
        {
            var o = changedCollection.Single(c => c.LookupKey.Equals(a));

            AttachToOrGet<TEntity, TKey>(entitySetName, pkColumnName, ref o);
            originalCollection.Add(o);
        });

        toRemove.ForEach(r =>
        {
            var o = originalCollection.Single(c => c.LookupKey.Equals(r));
            originalCollection.Remove(o);
        });
    }
```

This compares the new collection to the old one and works out which objects to add and which to remove. Note that the collections all contain objects which implement ILookupEntity.

My problems occur on the line where I call AttachToOrGet. This method I got from elsewhere on stackoverflow. I'm using this because I was often getting a message saying that "An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager" when attaching a new subobject. Hopefully you'll understand my confusion around this when I post the code of this method below:

```
    public void AttachToOrGet<TEntity, TKey>(string entitySetName, string pkColumnName, ref TEntity entity)
        where TEntity : class, ILookupEntity<TKey>
    {
        ObjectStateEntry entry;
        // Track whether we need to perform an attach
        bool attach = false;
        if (Context.ObjectStateManager.TryGetObjectStateEntry(new EntityKey(entitySetName, pkColumnName, entity.LookupKey), out entry))
        //if (Context.ObjectStateManager.TryGetObjectStateEntry(Context.CreateEntityKey(entitySetName, entity), out entry))
        {
            // Re-attach if necessary
            attach = entry.State == EntityState.Detached;
            // Get the discovered entity to the ref
            entity = (TEntity)entry.Entity;
        }
        else
        {
            // Attach for the first time
            attach = true;
        }
        if (attach)
            Context.AttachTo(entitySetName, entity);
    }
```

Basically this is saying if the entity is not already attached then attach it. **But my code is returning false on the Context.ObjectStateManager.TryGetObjectStateEntry line, but throwing an exception on the final line with the message "An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager".** To me this is paradoxical.

As far as I'm concerned I'm trying to achieve something very simple. Something it would take 20 minutes to write a stored procedure for. A simple database update. Frankly I don't care what is attached and what isn't because I don't wish to track changes or create proxies or lazy load or do anything else EF offers me. I just want to take a very simple object and update the database using a minimal number of trips between servers. How is this so complicated? Please someone help me - I've spent a whole day on this!

***Update***

Here's my ILookupEntity class:

```
public interface ILookupEntity<TKey>
{
    TKey LookupKey { get; }
    string DisplayText { get; }
}
```

Here's how it is implemented in CostCentre:

```
public partial class CostCentre : IFinancialCode, ILookupEntity<short>
{
    #region IFinancialCode Members

    public short ID { get { return CostCentreId; } }

    public string DisplayText { get { return string.Format("{0} - {1}", Code, Description); } }

    #endregion

    #region ILookupEntity Members

    public short LookupKey
    {
        get { return ID; }
    }

    #endregion ILookupEntity Members
}
```

Comment: have you tried Context.ObjectStateManager.TryGetObjectStateEntry(((IEntityWithKey)entity).EntityKey, out entry);

Comment: Hi Gary. My objects don't have EntityKey properties. They are POCO entities generated automatically (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/23df0450-5677-4926-96cc-173d02752313). Hence I have to instantiate a new EntityKey object, but my understanding is that this should still work.

Comment: In the example when `TEntity` is a `CostCentre`: Is `CostCentre.CostCentreId` the primary key property and correctly written? Does `entity.LookupKey` have the same value as `entity.CostCentreId` in your `AttachToOrGet`? (I'm asking because `TryGetObjectStateEntry` returns `false` if the entityset name or key property name is wrong. It doesn't throw an exception.) Can you perhaps show the `ILookupEntity<TKey>` interface and how it is implemented in `CostCentre` as an example?

Comment: Thanks for your time @Slauma - I've updated with the code you requested. CostCentre.CostCentreId is a primary key in the database but because I'm using POCO entities it is simply another Int16 in code. However my best guess at the problem is that when I add a CostCentre it attaches the CostCentre and all its children. When I add another CostCentre it attaches it then again tries to attach all children. If they both share the same child the problem occurs. I _think_. My frustration is that I'm not even updating these entities - I'm changing _relationships between_ the entities.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've worked through this and found a solution, but I can't say I understand it. The crucial ingredient came when I was performing a check after the comment by @Slauma. I wanted to check I was using the correct entity set name etc so I included the following lines near the top of my AttachToOrGet method:

```
        var key = new EntityKey(entitySetName, pkColumnName, entity.LookupKey);

        object temp;
        if (!Context.TryGetObjectByKey(key, out temp))
            throw new Exception(string.Format("No entity was found in {0} with key {1}", entitySetName, entity.LookupKey));
```

Bizarrely this alone resolved the problem. For some reason, once I'd called the TryGetObjectByKey then the ObjectStateManager.TryGetObjectStateEntry call actually started locating the attached entity. Miraculous. I'd love it if anyone can explain this.

By the way, I also needed to include the following code, but that's just because in my case the modelled entities are located in a separate assembly from the context itself.

```
        Assembly assembly = typeof(CostCentre).Assembly;
        Context.MetadataWorkspace.LoadFromAssembly(assembly);
```

Comment: `TryGetObjectByKey` queries the database when the entity is not in the context. If it finds the object with the given key in the DB it loads and attaches it. (And it finds always an object in the DB if I understand your procedure correctly since you are only changing relationships between *existing* objects.) So it's not surprising that `TryGetObjectStateEntry` returns `true` afterwards.

Comment: I think your hypothesis in your comment to the question is good: If you have children in different parents and these children can have the same key but are different objects, yes, your problem can occur. `AttachTo` attaches always the whole object graph but `TryGetObjectStateEntry` only asks for the parent's entry, so it can return `false` because the parent is not attached although for its children there are already objects with the same key attached. `TryGetObjectStateEntry` won't notice that, but `AttachTo` will.